# Auto Updates with App Installer stop working if user cancels the automatic update

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, appx

I ran into the following issue:

1. Installed client app v4.3.1.0 via .appinstaller
2. Upgraded the server to v5.3.1.0
3. Clicked to launch the client app and was prompted to Update
4. Clicked the Update button
5. While the update was running, I clicked "Cancel"
6. Now the app happily launches as v4.3.1.0 and no longer checks for updates.

I have tried restarting the PC and I have checked with Fiddler to verify no calls are being made to the server. It's like Windows has forgotten that the app was installed via the App Installer. I had to manually run the .appinstaller to get the app to v5.3.1.0, after which it began looking for updates on launch again.

Here are my configured update settings:

```
 <UpdateSettings>
        <OnLaunch HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" ShowPrompt="true" UpdateBlocksActivation="true" />
        <AutomaticBackgroundTask />
        <ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion>true</ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion>
  </UpdateSettings>
```

Comment: If you clicked "Cancel" when update was running, the appinstaller will not get update   package automatically, it is by design.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, that is not what happens in my testing. In my testing, that happens if you click Cancel *instead of* clicking Update. However, if you click Update and then Cancel *while* the update is running, the package does not update.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was fixed in Windows 1903 ( Build 18362). If you're using an earlier build, updating your OS to Build 18362 or greater may resolve the issue.